# Post request not working, response text returns blank space

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I'm trying to create an username 'claimer' that creates an account when a specific username becomes, or is/ available. I created a class with a get request which checks usernames and then calls the function `self.claimAccounts(name)` which then tries to create the account. However, for some unapperant reason it doesn't create the account. I've tried to see that the response is to the post request but it just returns a blank space.

The part of the code:

```
    def claimAccounts(self, username):
        payload = {
            'age': None,
            "dateOfBirth": "1989-01-18T00:00:00.00000Z",
            'confirmedEmail': email,
            'email': email,
            'country': 'GB',
            'firstName': None,
            'lastName': None,
            'nameOnPlatform': username,
            'password': password,
            'preferredLanguage': 'en',
            'legalOptinsKey': 'eyJ2dG91IjoiNC4wIiwidnBwIjoiNC4wIiwidnRvcyI6IjIuMSIsImx0b3UiOiJlbi1HQiIsImxwcCI6ImVuLUdCIiwibHRvcyI6ImVuLUdCIn0'
        }
        r = self.session.post("https://public-ubiservices.ubi.com/v3/users", headers=self.headers, data=payload)
        
        print(f"{Fore.LIGHTBLACK_EX}[+]{Fore.RESET} Claiming:       {username}")
        print(r.text)

    def checkAccounts(self):
        while not self.usernames.empty():
            name = self.usernames.get(); self.usernames.put(name)
            url = f"https://public-ubiservices.ubi.com/v3/profiles?nameOnPlatform={name}&platformType=uplay"

            r = self.session.get(url, headers=self.headers)
            if r.status_code == 200:
                self.checkedCount += 1
                if len(r.json()['profiles']) != 0:
                    print(f"{Fore.RED}[+]{Fore.RESET} Taken:          {name}")
                    self.checkedCount += 1
                else: 
                    self.checkedCount += 1
                    self.availableCount += 1
                    print(f"{Fore.GREEN}[+]{Fore.RESET} Available:      {name}")
                    self.claimAccounts(name)
```

The output:

```
[+] Taken:          taken
[+] Available:      gxzsontop151
[+] Claiming:       gxzsontop151
```

(Edit) Headers and request session

```
class GxClaimer():
    session=requests.Session()
    headers = {
        "Ubi-AppId": "c5393f10-7ac7-4b4f-90fa-21f8f3451a04",
        "Ubi-RequestedPlatformType": "uplay",
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36"}
```

Comment: What is the HTTP status code after *post()* ?

Comment: @BrutusForcus It gives a 415 status code. I added the headers to the original post for more clarity.

Comment: Instead of *data=payload* try *json=payload*

Comment: @BrutusForcus Oh, I totally forgot that I changed that, my bad. It now returns a 409 status code and a response text that states `{"moreInfo":"","errorCode":1301,"httpCode":409,"errorContext":"UbiServices.Users.Services","message":"The Ubi-Challenge header is required.","environment":"prod","transactionTime":"2021-09-29T18:30:16.5229371Z","transactionId":"2af88e30-3594-4934-91d6-60f281a15e53"}`. I checked the request again and the Ubi-Challenge header appears to be some sort of captcha. Would using a captcha harvester be useful in this case?

Comment: @BrutusForcus The 'captcha' is their own, very long base64 decoded string. If you want to, can you try to figure out anything, or any way to bypass this? I cant post it here so I created [this pastebin](https://pastebin.com/tscWr1sy)